# DFA to RE (Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages and Computation)

Tags: regex, regular-language, finite-automata

I've been struggling with this exercise for a while (3.2.3 from the book mentioned in the title). You are requested to transform a DFA to a RE. The automata is:

[image]

I tried to obtain the RE following the algorithm described in section 3.2.2 (state removal method), but I don't get the same RE than JFLAP (maybe it's equivalent, but I'm not sure if I'm applying the steps properly).

First step (state s removal):
[image]

Second step (state r removal):
[image]

The resulting RE is: L = `(1*+(010*1+00)(1(01)*10*1)*0)*`
(According to JFLAP it is `(1+00(10)*0+(01+00(10)*11)(0+1(10)*11)*1(10)*0)*`)

Could please someone tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: Even after the first step, something looks fishy; you can no longer get out of state r after removing state s, but you're not stuck in r in the original automaton; you can get back to q. Are you missing a transition r -1-> q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are removing `S` On `q`their must be loop `10`Because between `S`and `q`their is looping of `(01)`.
[image]

In above example When we elimnate state `1` ,on state `1` their is loop `10`
I hope so you easily understand it.